# Projection of a Symmetric Matrix onto the Matrix Probability Simplex

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, diagonalization, projection-matrices

The definition of probability simplex in $\mathbb{S}^n$:

$$\{X\in \mathbb{S}^n: X\geq 0, \text{tr}(X) = 1\},$$ where $\mathbb{S}^n$ is the vector space of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices.

A symmetric matrix $A\in \mathbb{S}^n$ has a diagonalization:

$$A = U\Lambda U^T$$

By the property of "trace of a matrix", we have:

$$\text{tr}(A) = \text{tr}(\Lambda)$$

So I think the projection of $A$ onto the probability simplex is the following:

1. $\pi(A) = U\Lambda^+U^T$, where $\Lambda^T$ is defined as:
   $$\lambda_i'=\lambda_i, \text{ for } \lambda_i\geq 0 \\ \lambda_i' = -\lambda_i, \text{ for } \lambda_i< 0$$

Note: $\pi()$ is the projection onto the probability simplex

> My question is how to satisfy the condition of the unity trace?

Comment: Why is $\pi(A) \geq 0?$

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri this is from the definition of probability simplex. $X\geq 0$

Comment: I do not think you can find a closed-form for the projection. AFAIK there is no such formula even for real numbers.

Comment: Is $ A $ a symmetric matrix to be begin with?

Answer (score 2):

There is no closed form solution I'm aware of.

But using [Orthogonal Projection onto the Intersection of Convex Sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492095) you will be able to take advantage of the simple projection to each set by itself.

So formulaitng the problem:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{X} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| X - Y \right\|}_{F}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & X \in \mathcal{S}_{1} \bigcap \mathcal{S}_{2} \bigcap \mathcal{S}_{3} \\ 
\end{aligned}$$

Where $ \mathcal{S}_{1} $ is the set of Symmetric Matrices ($ \mathbb{S}^{n} $), $ \mathcal{S}_{2} $ is the set of matrices with non negative elements and $ \mathcal{S}_{3} $ is the set of matrices with a trace of value 1.

The projection to each is given by:

1. Symmetric: $ \frac{Y + {Y}^{T}}{2} $.
2. Non Negative: $ {Y}_{i, j} = \max({Y}_{i, j} ,0) $.
3. Trace of Value 1: $ \operatorname{Diag} \left( Y \right) = \operatorname{Diag} \left( Y \right) - \frac{ \operatorname{Trace}(Y) - 1 }{n} $.

I wrote a MATLAB Code which implements the above in the framework linked. The code is accessible in my [StackExchange Mathematics Q1909139 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q1909139).

**Remark**:
The code doesn't assume $ Y $ is a symmetric matrix. If it does, since the other 2 projections don't ruin symmetry the projection onto symmetric matrix isn't required.