# Projection onto a Polyhedral Cone as Minimization of Different Norms

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matlab, convex-geometry, projection

Let $\mathbf c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $\mathbf c \neq \mathbf 0$.
Let $\mathbf A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.
Finally, let $p \in \mathbb N$.
What is the most efficient way to solve the following optimization problem?  Even better, does it have an analytical solution?

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{\mathbf x \in \mathbb{R}^n} & && \|\mathbf c - \mathbf x\|_p \\
\text{s.t.} & && \mathbf A \mathbf x \geq \mathbf 0, \\
& && \mathbf x\geq \mathbf 0. \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I am interested in the case where $\mathbf x = \mathbf c$ is not a feasible solution for the problem.

Right now, I am not too concerned about the value of $p$ (i.e., what type of norm we are minimizing). I'd be interested in a solution for $p = 1$, $p = 2$, or $p = \infty$. I know that for $p = 1$ and $p = \infty$ this can be reformulated as a linear program. However, given that the linear program has special structure, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to solve it than applying a generic linear programming algorithm.

Comment: I think for $ p = 1 $ any modern LP solver will be extremely efficient solving it as the form will be the classic one. The question is, are you after the case $ p = 2 $ as well?

Answer (score 2):

I think that for the case $ p = 1 $ any modern LP solver be as efficient as you think of since it will be the canonical form of LP.

For $ p = 2 $ you have the Orthogonal Projection problem which is a special case of [Orthogonal Projection onto the Intersection of Convex Sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492095).

All needed is to write the Matrix Inequality as a form of set of [Orthogonal Projection onto a Half Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318740).

I wrote a proof of concept using MATLAB with 2 methods:

1. Quadratic form of the Hybrid Steepest Descent (See Quadratic Optimization of Fixed Points of Non Expensive Mappings in Hilbert Space).
2. Consensus ADMM method which is related to the [Dykstra Projection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dykstra%27s_projection_algorithm).

I must add that I think an optimized Interior Points solver might be faster than each of them.

The MATLAB Code which is accessible in my [StackExchange Mathematics Q3599020 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q3599020).